# ¿Cómo puedo instalar completamente Go (Golang) detrás de un proxy?

Tags: go, proxy

He intentado instalar Go en mi pc con Windows 10, con el ejecutable no hay problemas, el problema es cuando intento ejecutar `go get golang.org/x/tour`. Estoy detrás de un proxy, y me da el siguiente error:

> go get golang.org/x/tour
>   package golang.org/x/tour: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/tour" (https fetch: Get https://golang.org/x/tour?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup golang.org: getaddrinfow: Éste es normalmente un error temporal durante la resolución de nombres de host y significa que el servidor local no recibió una respuesta de un servidor autoritativo.)

He abierto el proxy de la PC y no ha funcionado.

Comment: Asegurate si la ruta **url** esta bien escrito y siempre empieza la ruta **url** con **https://**, **ftp://**, etc.. Si no lo escribes bien el error que ta da va ser similar a cuando el servidor de resoluciones de **host** no reconoce la ruta **url**.

Comment: Es el único paquete que no te funciona?, Que tipo de configuración de proxy utilizastes (Un proxy de Go o de Windows?)

Comment: Tengo el proxy de la PC abierto

Comment: Perdon amigo tu respuesta sigue sin tener algún valor (No tiene los datos pedido). Quiero saber los detalles de que proxy programas y configuración utilizas para poder ayudarte